Printing values with trailing spaces
I am using keys to store a name.  And would like that any trailing spaces will also be printed.  Currently, trailing spaces are being removed when printed using the table.
For instance the command
\ditura
  {
    name={Likku Cirillu              },
  }

will strip the trailing spaces when printing with a table.
Also
\ditura {name={Likku}, role={else}}
\ditura {name={Likku Cirillu}, role={something}}

will place the two variant text in a different alignments, whereas I would like the two Likku to be aligned when printed.
Here is the relevant code
\tl_new:N \l_name_ditura_tl
\tl_new:N \l_role_ditura_tl
\tl_new:N \l_kmpn_ditura_tl

\cs_new:Nn \justr_ditura:n
  {

    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        {l}     {left}
        {L}     {left}
        {r}     {right}
        {R}     {right}
        {left}  {left}
        {right} {right}
      }
    {left}  % default for non-matching case.

}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \print_ditura:
  {
    \begin {tabular} { @{} l@{} }
      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_name_ditura_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_name_ditura_tl \\ }
    \end {tabular}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ditura:nn
  {
    \keys_set:nn {kvi_ditura} {#2}
    \begin {flush#1} \print_ditura: \end {flush#1}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ditura:nn { e }

\NewDocumentCommand {\ditura} { s O{r} m }
  {
    \ditura:en { \justr_ditura:n {#2} } {#3}
  }


Welcome TeX.SE @Bulldrive Your apparent issue is a normal and expected behaviour.

Please provide code people can compile. Help preparing a minimal working example to assist people helping you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228.

Unrelated but please follow the expl3 naming convention.

Not sure it’s the answer you’d like to hear/read, but TeX and LaTeX aren’t multiple-spaces aware by default. You can explicit need of non-breaking spaces so:
\ditura
  {
    name={Likku Cirillu~~~~~~~~~~~~~~},
  }

Not tested, but you can also check \mbox{} and \phantom{}.
Hope that helps.

Would one use a box then ?  I would like a box of text aligned at the same left position.  I am using tabular but consecutive calls to tabular with flushright produces different alignments.

Using ~ does produce the effect I want.  Would like to have the text from multiple calls to \ditura to align when printing on the right hand side of the document.

Was also introspecting the possibility of using an environment.

As gildux points out, in standard processing, any number of spaces in the input will be typeset as a single space in the output. A line break is also a space. A blank line is a paragraph break. Any number of consecutive blank lines are still a paragraph break.
But it's also important to understand that TeX doesn't output spaces at all, if by 'space' you are thinking of an explicit character. Instead, TeX uses an algorithm to figure out how much space to put and where. This is true for both vertical space and horizontal space.
This is why if you copy-paste text from a PDF produced by TeX, you may or may not end up with spaces in the correct places in the pasted text. It is a long time since this happened to me, so I don't know if it is still reproducible, but the reason it happened was that the space between words was sometimes too little for some viewers to recognise as a space between words.
There are ways to override this behaviour for specific stretches of input. So if you are inputting code, for example, you will probably want TeX to stick to the explicit spaces and line breaks in the source.
But I suspect what you actually want is to have the text left-aligned in the tabular column, so try
\ditura[l]{name={whatever}}

to get left-aligned whatever. The command you're using creates a right-justified column by default because you have O{r}. If you want the default to be left-aligned, change the r to l.

Good catch: setting the good column justification is a (more) global and elegant solution.

@cfr current pdftex does output real space characters according to some heuristics if \pdfinterwordspaceon is used.  But I think indentation can still not be reliably preserved in copy/paste as behavior depends on pdf viewer.

@user691586 Ah, interesting. I didn't know that. Does that make problems for line breaking? (I'm assuming it isn't default? Or is it?)

@cfr I am not very knowledgeable about this; copying-pasting from pdftex manual: \pdfinterwordspaceon/\pdfinterwordspaceoff... which turn on/off generation of faked interword spaces in the PDF output. This allows for better reflowing of text on the fly by PDF readers, better extraction of textual content, and is required by PDF/A. It does not affect the normal TeX justification with glue of the typeset output.

(cont.) This works roughly as follows: with \pdfinterwordspaceon, pdfTEX will guess when an inter- word space should be inserted, based on movement within some limits in horizontal direction. When found, pdfTEX inserts a true space character into the PDF page description for the viewers, and adjusts the next movement so that the next character will be in the expected position, according to normal TeX behavior.

@cfr see also 7 “Real” space glyphs in tagpdf doc.

@user691586 Aah. Thanks.
