Making an environment with a combined flushright tabular construct
I would like to construct an environment that uses flushright and tabular to print a set of lines.
Here is my attempt.  It has one argument intended to print the text in a single line.  Now I want to extend this to multiple lines.
\NewDocumentEnvironment {\ditura} {m}

  %% Begin Code
  {
    \begin{flushright}
      \begin{tabular} { @{} l@{} }
        {#1}
  }

  %% End Code
  {
      \end{tabular}
    \end{flushright}
  }

\mbox{} and \phantom{} could help with this.  Could one use a sort of key-value pairs to specify the values for each line ?
Consider the following text
Likku Cirillu
This and that 
Something and Something

Could this be inputted to the body of the environment within the flushright-tabular construct.
The idea is to print the multiline text as is but to the right side of the page.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/718810/printing-values-with-trailing-spaces#comment1787123_718810

it is hard to guess what you want but I would guess you want to remove the argument {#1} isn't helping, just use the body of the environment, then \begin{ditura}  line one \\ line 2 \\ line 3\end{ditura}  note environments are ditura not \ditura  and you want {} not {m} as you don't need an argument.

Your question is not clear and you still have provided no example showing desired input or result, but I would guess you want domething like

\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {ditura} {}
  %% Begin Code
  {%%%%
    \begin{flushright}%%%%
      \begin{tabular} {@{}l@{}}%%%
  }
  %% End Code
  {%%%%
      \end{tabular}%%%%
    \end{flushright}%%%
  }


\begin{document}

\section{Xxxx}
X\dotfill X

\begin{ditura}
  line one\\
  line 2\\
  the third line
\end{ditura}

\end{document}


Your understanding is correct.
